# SetWindowsHookEx with WH_MOUSE and TrackMouseEvent not capture WM_MOUSELEAVE

Tags: c++, winapi

I use SetWindowsHookEx() to capture WM_MOUSEMOVE and than use TrackMouseEvent to capture the WM_MOUSELEAVE, but the WM_MOUSELEAVE is not captured by my MouseHook.

Using Spy++ I can se that WM_MOUSELEAVE is fired, but my MouseHook not capture the message. Why?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHook(int nCode, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT   *pmh = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT   *) lp;

    if (nCode >= 0) {
        if( wp == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
            if(!tracking){
                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
                tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
                tme.hwndTrack = pmh->hwnd;
                TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
                tracking = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if( wp == WM_MOUSELEAVE){
        if(tracking){
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE & TME_CANCEL;
            tme.hwndTrack = pmh->hwnd;
            TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            tracking = false;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wp, lp);   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_MOUSELEAVE` isn't a true mouse message, it's generated by an internal timer proc that's established when you call `TrackMouseEvent` (that repeatedly checks if the mouse has left the window and sends a message to it when it does).

You could probably catch it with a `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook.

Comment: @jakaw You can also use GetCursorPoint() to get the location of the cursor, and GetWindowFromPoint(), to check when the cursor is not over the expected window.
In some cases it is better then using SetWindowHook.

Comment: With WH_GETMESSAGE works fine!
@TCS, thanks, but in this case it was not the better thing. But thanks for help!

Comment: fwiw I do not appear to be reliably receiving WM_MOUSELEAVE through a WH_GETMESSAGE hook on windows 7 x64 when specifying a child window hwnd.